# Could I assign a dedicate crawl database specific for a content source

Tags: 2016, crawling, searchserviceapplication

We are using SP2016. I have created a new content source to crawl another non-SharePoint website. It is working as expected. But I also need to save the index into separated crawl database.

By using New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlDatabase I can create a new crawl database but how could I map the content source to the new DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second Search Service Application to isolate your crawled content. You cannot assign a particular database to a particular content source otherwise.